# Questions about a proof

Tags: proof-explanation, calculus-of-variations, hamilton-equations

I am trying to understand a proof. The statement is

[image]

The proof begins with:
[image]
[image]

I have some questions about it:

- **ANSWERED** Since I am Italian, when it is said "the supreme is ATTAINED" what does it mean? Because $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$, so how couldn't be possible it?
- $|\xi_\nu|\rightarrow \infty$ means I am considering an increasing sequence?
- What is the aim of the Step 1, that is why must I proof that there is an $\xi$ for $H$ and that exists $R$ so that $|\xi|<R$?
- The fact that $\frac{w|\xi|}{|\xi|}>R+1$ derives from the hypothesis of the limit, but where does the following inequality comes from?
- **ANSWERED** I don't understand the Step 2, in fact I tried to find the other inequality but I only find out that

$(v-v')\xi'+f(x',u',\xi')-f(x,u,\xi') \leq H(x,u,v)-H(x',u',v') \leq (v-v')\xi+f(x',u',\xi)-f(x,u,\xi)$

Hope there will be someone who can help me, I have to write something on it and I would like only to understand it well. Thank you :)

Comment: I think "the supremum is attained" means "the supremum is not infinity", or equivalently "the supremum is a real number".  If one were to say "the supremum is not attained", one would be implicitly stating "the supremum is infinity", or that the set in consideration is not bounded above.

Comment: The last question you have, about step 2, you have already answered for yourself.  Just take the last inequality that you have written, and observe that this is precisely the inequality you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, how do I continue? It is said I have the continuity from the continuity of $f$ in $(x,u)$, so if $(x,u)\rightarrow(x',u')$, $H(x,u,v)\rightarrow H(x',u',v')$?

Comment: I spoke too soon about your first question!  Here, "the supremum is attained" means what the author states at (2.11).  So, the author is saying we can find a $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $H(x,u,v) = v\xi - f(x,u,\xi)$.